# Should I free a 0-size dynamic array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Hello I have a simple example: Since C++ allows a 0-size dynamic array of type `T` then how can I free it?

```
a = new int[0];
delete[] a;// UB?
```

As you can see above C++ compiler doesn't now about dynamic arrays size so it can be `0` so the code works. I also know that this array `a` works as past-end pointer so it cannot be neither de-referenced nor incremented/decremented.

- I don't know what happens behind the curtain in operator `new` in this case? Does it allocate memory or not? or does it fail?
- If I don't free this memory using `delete[] a;` is it a memory leak?
- Can assign to it like: `a = new int[10];`?

Comment: Subvert the problem.  `std::vector<int>`.  Now you have a zero size "array", and when it goes out of scope it will be handled automagically.  `new` is now the *new* `goto`.  You really shouldn't use it.

Comment: This can be tested. run `while(true) new int[0]` and check the memory profile.

Comment: Yes you need to free the memory with `delete[] a;`. You are allowed to read the pointer `a` but must not *deference* it. An interesting question is whether or not you are allowed to read the pointer `a + 1`. I don't *think* you are allowed to. Another interesting question is is the compiler allowed to set `a` to `nullptr`? I don't think it is.

Comment: I've asked the community on the points I've raised in the comment above. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442205/properties-of-a-pointer-to-a-zero-length-array.