# Properties of a pointer to a zero length array

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider

```
int main()
{
    auto a = new int[0];
    delete[] a; // So there's no memory leak
}
```

Between the copy initialisation and deletion, are you allowed to read the pointer at `a + 1`?

Furthermore, does the language permit the compiler to set `a` to `nullptr`?

Comment: As fr as I know, you're not allowed to read neither a not a+1.

Comment: @Fareanor: You can read `a` for sure (you certainly can't dereference it).

Comment: I'm asking this in response to my comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441437/should-i-free-a-0-size-dynamic-array/60441472#60441472

Comment: delete `a` sets `a` to NULL

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: That's hogwash.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Oh my ... no

Comment: @Bathsheba Oh right I meant "dereference" instead of "read". My bad.

Comment: Since C++ follows the "you don't get what you don't use/need" principle, I'm not sure a compiler would set `a` to `nullptr`. But it is only a guess.

Comment: I'm struggeling to understand what you mean exactly with "_read the pointer at `a + 1`_". Regarding the second question, it seems a decision was made before C++11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389428/7582247

Comment: @TedLyngmo: When I say "read the pointer at `a + 1`", is the following code `auto b = a + 1;` undefined behaviour? (I think it is).

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah, ok. I was looking for traps :-)

Comment: What is the point of `new int[0]` in the first place?

Comment: @Kit.: I'm thinking on those lines too. (And therefore I can't see why `nullptr` can't be a choice for `a`.)

Comment: @Ayxan I'd guess in the case where `0` is actually the result of some expression that you won't know until runtime. Since `new int[0]` is safe, it could save you worrying about some branching/special cases. Imagine if I were to initialize an `std::vector` with `std::vector<int> v(0);`.

Comment: Really, there is nothing special about how `new` works with a zero sized array relative to a non-zero sized array. How you handle it is basically homogeneous with how you handle any other dynamic array allocations. Edit : I'll admit it feels strange that `a` is both a pointer to the start of the array *and* a one-past-the-end pointer, but that happens with any empty range, like `begin()` and `end()` of an empty container.

Comment: There's no allocated memory at `a + 1`, let alone a pointer.  Did you mean to ask about the value of `a + 1`  ?

Comment: @M.M not the object to which `a + 1` may be pointing, but rather the pointer itself.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087042/10957435), but not exactly a duplicate, since you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>     auto a = new int[0];
> ```

According to [[basic.compound.3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3), the value stored in `a` must be one of the following:

1. A pointer to an object (of type `int`)
2. A pointer past the end of an object
3. Null
4. Invalid

We can rule out the first possibility since there were no objects of type `int` constructed. The third possibility is ruled out since C++ requires a non-null pointer to be returned (see [[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation.2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#2)). Thus we are left with two possibilities: a pointer past the end of an object or an invalid pointer.

*I would be inclined to view `a` as a past-the-end pointer, but I don't have a reputable reference to definitively establish that. (There is, though, a strong implication of this in [[basic.stc]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4), seeing how you can `delete` this pointer.) So I'll entertain both possibilities in this answer.*

> Between the copy initialisation and deletion, are you allowed to read the pointer at `a + 1`?

The behavior is undefined, as dictated by [[expr.add.4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4), regardless of which possibility from above applies.

If `a` is a past-the-end pointer, then it is considered to point to the hypothetical element at index `0` of an array with no elements. Adding the integer `j` to `a` is defined only when `0≤0+j≤n`, where `n` is the size of the array. In our case, `n` is zero, so the sum `a+j` is defined only when `j` is `0`. In particular, adding `1` is undefined.

If `a` is invalid, then we cleanly fall into "Otherwise, the behavior is undefined." (Not surprisingly, the cases that are defined cover only valid pointer values.)

> Furthermore, does the language permit the compiler to set `a` to `nullptr`?

No. From the above-mentioned [[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation.2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#2): *"If the request succeeds, the value returned by a replaceable allocation function is a non-null pointer value"*. There is also [a footnote](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#footnote-32) calling out that C++ (but not C) requires a non-null pointer in response to a zero request.

Comment: If it were an invalid pointer value, you'll have serious problems from http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4

Comment: @T.C. True, that does strongly imply that it cannot be an invalid pointer value.

Answer (score 26):

Per recent CWG reflector discussion as a result of [editorial issue 3178](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/3178), `new int[0]` produces what is currently called a ["past-the-end" pointer value](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.2).

It follows that `a` cannot be null, and `a + 1` is undefined by [[expr.add]/4](http://wg21.link/expr.add#4).

Comment: _"Per recent CWG reflector discussion as a result of editorial issue 3178, `new int[0]` produces what is currently called a "past-the-end" pointer value"_ This is not accurate. There wasn't much of discussion. One person suggested that the value should be "pointer past the end of an object", and this statement was questioned because in case of an array with `0` elements, there is no object to be past the end of.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer there seems no doubt that `a + 1` is undefined in any case,  so your point only pertains to whether `a` can be null?

Comment: There did not appear to be any disagreement about the intended semantics, nor that the current name for this category of pointer values is a poor fit for this scenario.

Comment: @M.M I think that `a + 1` is undefined and maybe the resulting pointer value will be called "pointer past the end". I'm not saying that the answer is wrong. It is slightly not accurate because it could be understood as that there was a lengthy discussion with a consensus that mere specifying that the result is "pointer past the end" is enough to resolve the issue. The problem with "pointer past the end" is that it is past the end of some object and subtracting `1` from such a pointer value gives one a pointer to the object, which probably shouldn't be the case for arrays of `0` elements.